# How do you pass an object parameter to a SOAP method call in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to make a soap request and the method I'm calling takes any number of objects define by this:

```
<xs:complexType name="thing">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="string1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="string2" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="string3" type="xs:long"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

How do I create an object like that in PHP and pass it to the soap method? Right now the (not working) code I have looks like this:

```
$obj->string1 = 'something';
$obj->string2 = 'something';
$obj->string3 = 'something';
$param = new SoapParam(new SoapVar($obj, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'method', 'http://ns'), 'paramName');

$soapClient->method($param);
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the body of the request of the shown method:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns2:method xsi:type="ns1:method">
    <string1>something</string1>
    <string2>something</string2>
    <string3>something</string3>
  </ns2:placeHolds>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

If I just pass $obj instead of creating a SoapParam, this is the body in the request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:method/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: Try passing $obj as the method parameter instead. If you're using a WSDL, PHP will figure it out itself.

Comment: that doesn't appear to be working either.

Comment: I've updated the question with the respective requests that are being sent.

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = new SoapClient('endpoint');

$sequence->string1 = 'something';
$sequence->string2 = 'something';
$sequence->string3 = 'something';

$obj = array();
$obj['sequence'] = $sequence;

$param = new SoapParam(new SoapVar($obj, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT), 'paramName');

$client->__soapCall('method',array($param));
```